# Is the "same-origin" implied when using "frame-ancestor" in the CSP header?

Tags: attack-prevention, websites, same-origin-policy

If my `Content-Security-Policy` is set to the following:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
```

Does it also imply:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
```

Or is it a lot safer to put both rules?

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'
```

---

Updated, as mentioned by  AlphaD in a comment, the "same-origin" is indicated by `default-src` and not an hypothetical `same-origin` option. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: When you write same-origin do you mean something like default-src 'self'? I don't think your CSP examples #2,#3 are valid syntax.

Comment: @AlphaD Ah! I understand now. I found a couple of links that helped tremendously too. I updated my question to showing `default-src 'self'` too.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found two documents that helped me answer my own question.

The page is specifically about the `Content-Security-Policy` header:

https://content-security-policy.com/

and it shows interesting examples of CSP.

Now on Mozilla, we have a [default-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/default-src) page which clearly explains that the `default-src` is the default for all the other `...-src` options. Changing another option takes priority for that option. So in my example above, if I do:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
```

then I do not need to add `frame-ancestors 'self'` since it will be the default already. However, just doing:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
```

Does not affect the `default-src`, whatever that might be.